# Looking for a specific adventurer manga/anime

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga (which also got an anime adaption I think) is an adventurer manga. I remember a specific chapter where he is headed to his hometown for a mission (together with another female adventurer if I remember correctly) and meets with his mother who is very passionate about him. The father sees them and punches the son mistaking him for a stranger harassing her. The mother get furious and beats the father to a pulp. I think his mother was also an adventurer or part of some hidden organization (someone strong at the very least). Later they beat a demon near the hometown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it myself. It is *Noumin Kanren no Skill bakka Agetetara Nazeka Tsuyoku Natta* or *I've somehow gotten stronger when I improved my Farm-Related Skills*

Comment: You can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. Although, as a self-accept, it won't let you complete that for another 47 hours or so.